# May your bakery keep or keeps?

Tags: grammar

I have to use a sentence which is:
May your bakery keep flooding with customers.
Will it be keep or keeps. As bakery is singular, so is keeps fine?
Can anyone explain the logic? Thank you so much.

Comment: Neither. May your bakery remain flooded with customers.

Comment: I keep, you keep, he keeps, they keep.

Comment: In general, if I am to use a sentence, may your "object" "verb", then will the verb be plural or singular?

Comment: Auxiliary verb "may" is followed by the infinitive of the verb.  May he run like the wind.  He may enter the house.  You do not inflect the verb (runs, enters).  Same for other auxiliary verbs: can, could, shall, should, will, would, may, might, must.

Comment: @GEdgar, infinitive and not subjunctive?

Comment: @Juhasz: For the subjunctive mood, English uses the infinitive form of the verb.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English